# Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting this error

**Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/50l75oqnyx

**issue is on this line index.js** line no:12

```
store.dispatch(testAction('StackOverflow'));
```

**I am trying to dispatch action from outside**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the return object under `abc.actions.js`, you should return an object with a property "type" and then the action you want to execute. But you instead of defining type you are defining `action:Actions.SET_IMAGE` the correct way is `type: Actions.SET_IMAGE`.

```
export function testAction(text) {
  console.log(text);
  console.log("ddddd");

  return {
    type: Actions.SET_IMAGE,
    text
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests you should have a `type` property specified while dispatching the action which you don't have in `testAction`. Change your `action` key to `type` and it will work

```
export function testAction(text) {
  console.log(text);
  console.log("ddddd");
  return {
    type: Actions.SET_IMAGE,
    text
  };
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zq20m7lzzl)

Answer (score 0):

Your action at *acb.action.js* does not contain a `type`

```
export function testAction(text) {
  console.log(text);
  console.log("ddddd");
  return {
    action: Actions.SET_IMAGE,
    text
  };
}
```

and your reducer will take `payload`(abc.reducer.js line 12) not `text` as you do, so you should change to

```
export function testAction(text) {
  console.log(text);
  console.log("ddddd");
  return {
    type: Actions.SET_IMAGE,
    payload: text
  };
}
```